# How can I accomplish this layout using proper markup and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a block on the left and a box which contains text to its right, but I don't want the text that wraps to drop under the block. It should stay with the confines of a rectangle that is adjacent the block. This is how a table would behave, but I'm not sure what the best way to accomplish this outside of one is.

I hope this fiddle will clarify: http://jsfiddle.net/bernk/Ck7cj/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="block">BLOCK</div>
<div class="text">This is a text box that wraps onto at least two lines</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of floating you can use `display:table-cell`:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ck7cj/1/)**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
.block {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 70px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.text {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I've thought about that, but is that an "appropriate" us of `display: table-cell`?

Comment: is it OK because even though the elements are being displayed as table cells they are not marked up as such?

Comment: @bernk - Yup, that's one of the points of doing it with CSS over `<table>` elements.

Comment: One more thing, is it OK if an element which is being displayed as a table cell is not contained by an element which is displayed as table or table row?

Comment: Yes, the same rules for HTML elements don't apply to styles. So you don't need to nest a display table-cell in a table row in a table CSS-wise, where you do with plain HTML.

Comment: Thanks for all your informative answers. Do you know of a good source where I could read into this more?